# How do we feel about [spoiler] as a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, spoilers

I would've thought that for some questions regarding quests that occur late in-game that can be considered a spoiler we could've tagged it [spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) but, as I went to edit a question, I realized there is no spoiler tag.

Would this community benefit from the tag?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [spoiler](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoiler) tag has existed in the past, but was deemed problematic and removed:

[Spoiler alert: [spoiler] dies](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/spoiler-alert-spoiler-dies)

Comment: Damn you! you beat me to it because of my toaster :(

Comment: Then is there a way for editors to mark certain story sequence infomation I.E. [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131783/how-do-i-make-a-pick-up-for-smoke-on-the-water) as a spoiler? I attempted to just make the text sent to the player marked as spoiler but 6 char max was killing it.

Comment: @ColeBusby I don't really see how that text spoils anything.

Comment: @ColeBusby Mo rep, mo editing privileges. (Full editors have no character minimum limit.) As I suggested in the comment there, just leave a comment for the OP or a full editor to implement the edit.